# Increase size of Task View Window Thumbnails

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to increase the size of the window thumbnails in Windows 10 in Task View? The default is quite small for me, when I generally have only a few windows open, and they're all bunched up in the top left corner. Is there a way to increase the size via the registry?